# External app calls single procedure in Oracle package that has 200 procedures?

Tags: database, stored-procedures, oracle11g

Oracle 11g 
An oracle package with approximately 200 procedures.
An external app connects to this Oracle database and calls a single procedure in this package.  Is the entire package loaded into memory on the Oracle server or is only 'the procedure being called' loaded into memory on the oracle server?

Would there be a performance gain by putting these 200 procedures in separate (smaller) packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the entire package will be loaded in order to allow the one procedure to be executed.

If your system is so well-tuned that reading an extra kb or two of code into cache is a major source of waits, refactoring the package may improve performance.  It seems unlikely, however, that you have such a system.  The vast, vast majority of systems would see no improvement.  And breaking things up would potentially slow down other systems that call multiple procedures in the package because they'd have to do multiple read operations to load them into memory.  Of course, this "slow down" would be of the same order of magnitude as the "speed up" you'd get by refactoring the code for the caller that only calls one procedure.

Realistically, I would strongly suspect that a package with 200 procedures needs to be refactored from a maintainability perspective.  It seems unlikely that all 200 are sufficiently closely related to belong in a single package.  I wouldn't do it for performance reasons but I would for maintenance reasons.